# Getting index of column in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to create a custom column menu item, which will take all of the rows in the column, determine the range of those numbers, and determine the percentile of that row within the range - to assign a color on a scale of red to green. I have the colorization algorithm and function [set up already](http://jsfiddle.net/7Luwyyxr/2/), from when I did this thing before, but before I wasn't using angular, I was using [tablesaw](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw). Now I need to be able to use the column's menu to fire this function.

The only thing I need is to **determine the index of the column whos menu was opened**, so that the function knows which column to select and change the CSS for with the `:nth-child(index)` jquery/css psuedoclass selector.

My setup with angular and this function is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/l96Nubhoe2xrK32Kw1yI?p=preview

Comment: can you include the relevant code in the question section? if the external site is down, the question would seem incomplete

Comment: Their documentation for column menu customization seems to have a clue:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu

Specifically, `this.context.col` should return the column object that was clicked on. I don't see an index property but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: @nairys That got me far enough - I logged out `this.context.col`, then found `this.context.col.colDef.name`, and iterated through the $scope.columnDefs array to find the index where the name was equal to that. Good Idea, thanks.

Comment: NP - hopefully you don't have any columns with identical names. Glad it helped.

Comment: @J-Dizzle rather than taking index from the name, what you can do is : search `this.context.col` in array `$scope.columnDefs` for the index using `indexOf`, this would solve the problem of having more than one columns with same display name